# Why can't I update my ObservableCollection with Filtered CollectionView attached during unit testing?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, nunit

I've got an `ObservableCollection` in a `ViewModel` that I need to modify in code on a background thread (using a `Task` object). I've also got an `ICollectionView` attached to that collection. When I modify the collection at run-time, the code runs fine. In unit testing I get the error, "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

I create the collection thusly (on the UI thread at run-time):

```
    CashDeliveryDepots = new ObservableCollection<CashDeliveryDepot>();
    FilteredCashDeliveryDepots = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CashDeliveryDepots);
```

and modify it using this code (which will be running on a non-UI thread at run-time):

```
    CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        foreach (var depot in depots)
        {
            CashDeliveryDepots.Add(depot);
        }
    });
```

The `CurrentDispatcher` class executes code according to whether or not there is an application dispatcher.

```
internal static class CurrentDispatcher
{
    internal static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        if (Application.Current != null)
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        else
            action();
    }
}
```

So at run-time the dispatcher is picked up correctly, the observable collection is updated and the filtered view updates too. When running the unit tests I get the exception at the point of trying to add a new item to the collection.

Can anyone suggest a way around this so I can get my tests working?

Comment: Do you have it solved?